# Search in GDrive only the first 5 topics

Tags: search, google-drive-api

is there a parameter in GDrive to start a search with "DriveApp.searchFiles". After the first e.g. 10 hits the command stop the searching.

Currently I can only manage to search for all hits, but this takes too long.

Greetings

I try this GScript:

```
function listAllFiles() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "GutenTag" and "' + MyAccount + '" in owners');
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Method *[update]*

If you would rather not use looping, as this can slow down the `DriveApp.searchFiles` function in your actual environment, you may want to try using the [Google Drive API Advanced service *list* method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A5%2C%22q%22%3A%22name%20contains%20%27GutenTag%27%20and%20%27menesesj102%40gmail.com%27%20in%20owners%22%7D#query-parameters) and include a `pageSize` query parameter in the API call request. Here is a sample script:

*[Updated]*

```
function listAllFilesWithLimit() {
   var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  const res = Drive.Files.list({
    "pageSize": 5,
    "q": `name contains 'GutenTag' and '${MyAccount}' in owners`
  });

  res.files.forEach(x => console.log(x.name))
}
```

***Prerequisites:***

Add the **Drive API Advance Service** in your Services section on the Apps Script Editor:

[image]

### Demo

> *The API request only returned 5 results, rather than retrieving all of the matching files in the drive in a single operation.*

[image]

Comment: If there are any misunderstanding on this matter, feel free to comment.

Comment: I know the route via the loop. However, this means that the entire search query is processed completely and, in my case, this takes a very long time. By shortening, my goal was also to save time.

Comment: I see. The built-in `DriveApp.searchFiles` method only accepts a single parameter, so it may not be able to handle your use case. However, not sure if you've tried this one, but you could try using the Drive API Advanced service, which allows you to add a query parameter `pageSize` that would gather the request data by size in one go, which in theory would be faster. I have updated the answer to include some sample code on how to use this service.

Comment: "Drive.Files.list" looks perfect. Thanks
The additional features are very complex. Do you know of any script wizards for writing command lines like this?

Comment: That's good to know that this method works for you. About script wizards, I would suppose you're referring to using AI when coding.

Comment: Using script wizards is not really advisable practice when formulating code as there could be chances of inaccuracy. I have translated the script above based on the original script logic. Basic knowledge in HTTP interfaces for calling API is required for this. However, in Google Apps Script, this is simpler as this uses advanced services. You may review the [official Google Apps Script advance services docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) & official [files.list method in Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: AI is a very good tip and a very good tool, but we all have to be very careful not to forget everything because of AI. :)